# Insert form into database

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm trying to insert my form information into a database that is already created. So far I have:

```
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
      Username:
      Password:
      Confirm Password:
      <input type="submit">
      if loops {
        send alert and return back to form page; }
    </form>
```

My question is: using this code, will the user information still be sent to the database file if the if loops are activated or will I need an exit statement after every if loop? (I do not want any information sent if the if loops are activated).

Thanks

Comment: please elaborate, what loop you are talking about???

Comment: try AJAX if you want to send something and checking asynchronously..although I am not very sure what u are really looking for..add some more line in your question regarding the problem

Comment: AJAX is not the answer to every question

Comment: @Dagon yup sure..but may be the one out of many..and that is why its a comment ;)

Comment: so sick of AJAX being the answer when regular synchronous are fine

Comment: Thank you for down voting me... I didn't think it was hard to understand lol. I am talking about the if loops. I am using those loops to make sure that the Username, password, confirm password are containing the correct information (aka password == confirm password) otherwise it will send an alert message and return the user back to the form page for a second chance.

Comment: @swapnesh Why use another method when you can use simple coding ;)

Comment: @Llama First of all ..i haven't downvoted you..and second I am not clear with what you are asking ..when I commented i thought you are looking you something to save data before submit like wise thats why I suggested AJAX

Comment: I'm glad everyone is enjoying this form... First off @swapnesh I never said you did, it was a general comment for who ever was reading. I guess people still don't understand what I am asking for so I'm just going to close this question and just do trial and error.

Comment: @Llama sometimes I really dont understand how stack works..when u can vote for close then why to down rate the question?? a day or two before I saw a post voted +4 and on a single comment  it went to -5 ...but yeah its good to see u enjoyed with this..just remember the main motto is to learn from here..happy coding!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `inputs` on your form:

```
 <form action="insert.php" method="post">
       Username: <input type="text" name="username">
       Password: <input type="password" name="password"> 
       Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="confirm">
       <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
```

Then on `insert.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $Error = 0;
 if (!isset($_POST['username'])){
  $Error++;
 }
 if (!isset($_POST['password'])){
  $Error++;
 }
 if (!isset($_POST['confirm'])){
  $Error++;
 }

 if ($Error > 0){
  echo "Error in HTML Validation";
  exit; 
 }


// continue post verification here. 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also validate your form in client-side and it is faster and reduces server load:

```
 <form name="myForm" action="insert.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return validateForm()>
      Username:
      Password:
      Confirm Password:
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

And write a javascript for validating your form:

```
<script type="text/javaScript">
function validateForm()
{
  //Here will be your validation logic
  //if input doesn't meet your requirement then return false 
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  if(x is not an email address) 
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```